# Can outerHTML be used with createElement

Tags: javascript, dom

I am reading all the list-items (raw HTML) from a web page, sorting them, and now wish to relist them in a new order.  I find that the outerHTML attribute cannot seemingly be set after using createElement, and I'm thinking that is an undocumented restriction.  I end up with empty list-items (so currently I use innerHTML and remove the imbedded li and /li).  Simple failing example follows.  Thoughts?

```js
const myList = document.querySelector("#ulist"); // the ID of an unordered list
let newHTML = document.createElement("li"); // have to start with something …
// newHTML.innerHTML = "This is the contents of the LI..."; // THIS WORKS!
newHTML.outerHTML = "<li>This is a new LI</li>"; // THIS DOES NOTHING!
myList.appendChild(newHTML);
```

```html
<ul id="ulist">
</ul>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML  "If the element has no parent element, setting its outerHTML property will not change it or its descendants. Many browsers will also throw an exception."

Comment: You have to set the parent of the `newHTML` element before you can set it's `outerHTML`.

Comment: In this instance it makes more sense to set the innerHTML of the existing element.  After all, if you create it, use it.  Otherwise you're making it for no reason.

Comment: Tapler, thank you; but to clarify, I already have the full list-item HTML, which includes a class, so it would be easier to use it as-is.

Taco, with your and Tapler's explanation, I guess this just won't work out for me because I have nothing but list-items and don't NEED a parent.  If you can think of how I can "fix" this, please give an example; otherwise, thank you anyways!

Comment: @FredB - that makes no sense. You're adding the li to its parent in the last line of your js code. Just move it to before the outerHTML assignment. But really think you'd be better off using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) on `myList` instead anyway.

Comment: @Alohci - brilliant - it works!  I didn't realize I could change newHTML after it was appended.  I will investigate insertAdjacentHTML next, and I thank you very much for continuing my JavaScript education.

Comment: @Alohci - to complete this discussion, again you are correct, that insertAdjacentHTML works perfectly, completely eliminating the need for my dummy createElement followed by using outerHTML.  I just replaced the appendChild with "myList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',li)" to keep inserting my pre-existing li's at the end of the unordered list.  I wasn't given the option for a thumbs-up, but you got it!

Answer (score 1):

As @Alohci pointed out in comments; use [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead. Adjacent means near, close to, preceding or following. And with insertAdjacentHTML() you specify where you want to insert the HTML in relation to existing content.

Example usage:

```js
const myList = document.querySelector("#ulist");
myList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>This is a new LI</li>");
```

```html
<ul id="ulist"></ul>
```

Useful visualisation from MDN of the position values:

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
<p>
  <!-- afterbegin -->
  foo
  <!-- beforeend -->
</p>
<!-- afterend -->
```